# What’s happening? Unresponsive Ubuntu after interference pattern

Tags: dual-boot, suspend

I have a remaining problem with an interference pattern on Ubuntu 18.04 and it remains until now, Ubuntu 20.04, 21.04 (Mint), dual boot, with two Ubuntu systems and an old win7 system, which I never use online. So, triple boot.

Laptop VAIO PCG-71211M, with 8 or 4 GB RAM. The substitute 8 GB RAM was already tested by the distributor.

Best demonstrated by the image below (memTest after restart) which is related to [Interference pattern on Ubuntu 16.04 GUI output / unresponsive / crash of system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1267892), because it first shows a pattern like in this other post. Then after restart with MemTest version 4.xx from a rescue USB stick, the vertical columns disappear slowly, and the blinking colored graphical characters get lesser.

When this pattern happens, the OS usually becomes non responsive.   PC reset button is the only way out.

The later I react to the disturbance the more graphical characters cover the memTest screen.

It’s a reoccurring ‘feature’ since 1 year  Linux 4.15.xx generic  and low latency up to to current 5.xx versions so far same issue.

After running memTest restart of all systems is possible with more or less disturbances. So, I started to repeat the memTest treatment. And changed to the original 4GB RAM module set. But the frequency of occurrence increases. From 1 month, one year ago, to 1 - 4 days,  now

Anyone know what or why this is happening...?

Is this the Effect of the Intel CPU hardware bug Spectre - Meltdown?

It might also be correlated to the suspend mode which I used to employ for up to ten days or, say, 20 switch off periods.

I didn’t reinstall anything, because I’ll prefer to get an idea about the reason first.

[memoryTest after restarting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zj8uE.jpg)

I have to reopen the case again. The problem occurred on another machine. Very old, 386, Toshiba satellite M40X-112, model PSM4XE-00U00CGR. Dualboot OS WinXP/Ubuntu 18.04. Running Ubuntu. Similar images. I could shut down the Laptop with kind of random Alt-F4 Return sequences.

Comment: If you're getting that problem in Memtest then it's an hardware problem, obviously. Very likely your graphics is defective.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: Thanks for the comment. memTest is the only way to get back on track. It seems to repair the damage piece by piece. But the problem is more stubborn. It comes back over and over again. And if it isn’t the memory’s fault, where can the problem reside? Hard disk? MBR? Grub?

Comment: @ChaganAuto: 2nd. So I have to check the place where the graphics are produced? I thought for Laptops it would be borrowed from RAM. Why is the system unresponsive for keyboard strokes, then? Thanks again.

Comment: I'll post a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

This question is off-topic because the problem is entirely **hardware**, a failure of the graphics card likely due to overheating.

> memTest is the only way to get back on track. It seems to repair the damage piece by piece. But the problem is more stubborn. It comes back over and over again. And if it isn’t the memory’s fault, where can the problem reside? Hard disk? MBR? Grub?

**Memtest has absolutely nothing to do with it**. And the problem is absolutely not related with HDD.

Here's what happens: The defective graphics card overheats and start generating the artifacts shown in the question, a very typical symptom. The next thing you do is run the memory test which does just that, test the RAM. CPU, graphics, drives, etc. barely function during the whole test. The test itself, albeit showing a graphical interface, is extremely low demanding on graphical and computational resources - it's not much more than what late 1980's computers like ZX Spectrum or Commodore 64 were capable of already - therefore the whole system and the graphics card particularly cools down thus giving the impression that it "repairs the damage piece by piece".

> So I have to check the place where the graphics are produced? I thought for Laptops it would be borrowed from RAM.

Laptops aren't different than desktops. They have the same basic components, same sub-systems, etc. but in some cases those components are specifically designed for "mobile" (smaller, quieter, more energy efficient, ...).

Any modern computer either has a (discrete) graphics card or an (integrated) graphics chip. The latter used to reside in the motherboard's chipset but now the more common types are the ones embedded in the CPU itself as just another CPU's layer. Any can fail and yours failed, badly. A cursory search for your laptop's model suggests it has some old AMD dGPU.

In conclusion, your laptop needs repairs. Please take it to a professional service for assessment. The bad news: It's probably not worth it. This model is being sold used for as little as 170USD. The repair itself may cost more than that, not including parts.

Comment: While I have learned a lot from this answer, and your points are very sound, I just wanted to note you don't need to be that _salty_ about the whole thing :)

Comment: @Levente I know, but certain assertions make my head go boooooom. My initial comment under the question should've been enough because it's that sort of thing that "everybody knows".

Comment: "My initial comment under the question should've been enough" — I disagree, because I then I would not have learnt your very powerful way of considering the effects of heat in components, and also your reverse-engineering of how people arrive at false conclusions. :) (Ah and also how quickly it's possible to forward-think to the point of prognostizing the economic aspects of the troubleshooting.)

Comment: I have to reopen the case again. The problem occurred on another machine. Very old, 386, to shiva satellite M40X-112, model PSM4XE-00U00CGR. Dualboot OS WinXP/Ubuntu 18.04. Running Ubuntu.